# Configuring multiple keyboards for windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

This may seem on the surface to be a very basic question but its something I've never been able to do. And I'm wondering if someone can help as its really impacting my scripting!

I'm a Brit living in Japan, my computer keyboard is a Japanese model with all the icons in the Japanese place but my setup on windows is to think the keyboard is British- I'm just so used to everything been in its proper place and don't have to look at the keyboard to type.
For most purposes this is great.

However, I can't seem to be able to do a back slash. Where it should be in the bottom left is on a Japanese keyboard an extra big tab, back slash is instead over on the bottom right, near forward slash, a key which does nothing on my setup.

Does anyone know a way to configure windows 7 so that when I alt and shift to switch my typing language (something easy to do. Don't need help there) it also switches the type of keyboard it thinks I have. Or, even better, customise the layout of my keyboard.
Hope this doesn't get closed as many other config questions seem to have been as my being able to script depends upon this!

Comment: Have you tried, for example, searching the web for "keyboard configuration windows 7" ? The very first result is a step-by-step description, straight from MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258824 (Also, welcome to StackOverflow, the site for _programming_ questions; questions on computer _use_ are better suited for our sister site, http://superuser.com/ )

Comment: Yeah, that microsoft guide is to the basic setup I have now. Not the fully working setup I want.
This is programming related, the whole reason I need the backslash is for programming. I was unaware of that other website I must say, will try there if the mods here are having a boring day :p.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you meant. Maybe try remapping the other tab to backslash using the freeware utility SharpKeys: http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35.html (I still think your question is _not_ programming related: "I _use_ a computer for X" is not programming, not even when "X=programming")